# How to create a Plaid LinkToken using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, plaid

I believe Plaid updated its createLinkToken documentation, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm taking a course, and here is the old code that worked in using a FirebaseFunction to create a link token with Plaid:

```
exports.createPlaidLinkToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const customerId = context.auth.id;

  const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({
    clientID: functions.config().plaid.client_id,
    secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
    env: plaid.environments.sandbox,
    options: {
      version: '2019-05-29',
    },
  });

  return plaidClient.createLinkToken({
    user: {
      client_user_id: customerId,
    },
    client_name: "Bon Voyage",
    products: ["auth"],
    country_codes: ["US"],
    language: "en"
  }).then((apiResponse) => {
    const linkToken = apiResponse.link_token;
    return linkToken;
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "Unable to create plaid link token: " + err);
  });
});
```

I've tried a number of things.  I know `plaid.Client` is now `new.Configuration` but I can't seem to figure out the rest.  Any helpers?

---

You can see in the comments below what I've tried.  I've modified the code as follows, and now receive Error status code 400.

```
const plaid = require('plaid');
const { Configuration, PlaidEnvironments, PlaidApi } = require("plaid");

exports.createPlaidLinkToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
 
  const customerId = context.auth.uid;

  const configuration = new Configuration({
    basePath: PlaidEnvironments.sandbox,
    baseOptions: {
      headers: {
        plaid_client_id: functions.config().plaid.client_id,
        plaid_secret: functions.config().plaid.secret,
        plaid_version: '2021-05-20'
      },
    },
  });

 const plaidClient = new PlaidApi(configuration); 

 return plaidClient.linkTokenCreate({
      user: {
        client_user_id: customerId,
      },
      client_name: "Bon Voyage",
      products: ["auth"],
      country_codes: ["US"],
      language: "en"
    })
    .then((apiResponse) => {
       const linkToken = apiResponse.data.link_token;
        // const linkToken = response.link_token
      return linkToken;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "internal",
        " Unable to create plaid link token: " + err
      );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this question as you haven't mentioned what you've tried or what error you are experiencing. Have you reviewed the sample implementations in the docs that show how to do this, including the sample code in the [Quickstart](https://github.com/plaid/quickstart) and [Tiny Quickstart](https://github.com/plaid/tiny-quickstart)?

Off the top of my head, I do see that this sample code specifies an API version of 2019-05-29, which is not compatible with the latest version of the Node client library that uses `new.Configuration`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Well the first line that triggers an issue is this one: ```const plaidClient = new plaid.Client({``` with log error of ```Unhandled error TypeError: plaid.Client is not a constructor```

Comment: So I removed the line with ```new plaid.Client``` as I believe this is outdated.  Looking to the new docs, I added ```new PlaidApi(configuration)``` (I can post the code later). The log error is now ```Unhandled error TypeError: plaidClient.createLinkToken is not a function```  My thought is that Plaid changed the name of createLinkToken to something else.  I think it's linkTokenCreate but not positive.  I'll try that and report results.

Comment: Maybe this is progress, but the error is now: ```Error: Request failed with status code 400```  My thought is that perhaps ```const linkToken = apiResponse.link_token``` needs to be ```const linkToken = apiResponse.data.link_token```   I will try and report back.

Comment: Same error of Status Code 400.  The change does add like 30-40 more entries to my logs.  Just so you or any other kind souls who are helping need to see the code exactly as I am using, I'll post above in an update.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this full error would help, but here is what I have: ```Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:269:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections```

Comment: did you ever figure this out I am having the same error